# Cryptographically secure DRNG for pure js?

Tags: javascript, random, cryptography, random-seed, cryptoapi

I am looking for a DRNG/DRBG/CSPRNG (cryptographically secure) in js. My application is currently using the web crypto api, and I am looking to use a DRNG to generate multiple, identical AES keys (using the web crypto deriveKey() function) on separate client devices, sharing the seed securely. I know there are several HMAC_DRBG libraries for node js, but I am looking to use native js only (or some pure math function which I can convert). Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey. The latter can use PBKDF2 or HKDF, depending on the entropy of your seed.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk is there any way to use derivekey to generate multiple consecutive keys. I currently use a seed to generate a single key, but I want multiple clients to be able to generate many keys (as shared keys) for ongoing correspondence.